# I need a regex to get a value from a string of two values seperated by TO or -

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to get two values and return the bigger values from a string.

For example if my String is: `0.87 TO 0.88(WATER=1)` I need to return the bigger value `0.88`.

The string may also contain `-` instead of `TO`, for example `0.87 - 0.88(WATER=1)`,
in this case also I need to return the bigger value `0.88`.

I tried following Pattern matcher also:

```
      ` Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("0.87 - 0.88(WATER=1)");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Result-->"+m.group(0));
        }`
```

But i am getting: 0.87

Comment: A regular expression can't help pick between the values, but it can help extract them from your string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define how to match your numbers. Here's an example pattern:

```
String decimalPattern = "\\d+\\.?\\d*";
```

Then, you can search your string for `<decimal number> TO <decimal number>` or `<decimal number> - <decimal number>` as follows:

```
Pattern pattern =
    Pattern.compile(String.format("(%1$s) (?:TO|-) (%1$s)", decimalPattern));

Matcher m = pattern.matcher("0.87 TO 0.88(WATER=1)");
if (m.find()) {
  Double max = Math.max(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)),Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)));
  System.out.println(max);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if the input is always in the form of "X-Y(WATER=1)" or "X to Y(WATER=1)", you can extract the two values and use ">" to get the bigger value.

As far as i know, you cannot compare numerical values using regex.

Comment: I think extracting the values is a key part of the problem and needs to be part of any good solution.